# Open text file and append new text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a text that I create and then later want to append text to it. But I'm getting a error: Invalid procedure call or argument.

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim Fileout As Object
Dim filePath As String
filePath = "C:\myFile.txt"


If FileExists(filePath) = False Then
Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath, True, True)
Fileout.Write Msg
Fileout.Close
Else
Set Fileout = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, ForAppending, TristateFalse) <<<<<== ERROR HERE
Fileout.Write Msg
Fileout.Close
End If

Function FileExists(strFullPath As String) As Boolean
'Check if a file or folder exists
If Not Dir(strFullPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileExists = True
End Function
```

Comment: At which point is the error being thrown?  What have you attempted already to rectify the problem?

Comment: You have modified your question to a completely other question.

Comment: Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. If you now have a new or additional question, create a new post and ask it there; you can link back to this one if needed for reference.

Comment: "Chinese characters" cannot be fixed based on this code snippet, since we don't know what the contents of `Msg` is nor its data type. *However* because it is "unintentionally chinese," it is probably a unicode/UTF string format problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I'm getting a error: Invalid procedure or argument.

```
Set Fileout = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, ForAppending, TristateFalse)
```

You are passing `TristateFalse` as argument 3. It should be argument 4.

Please read the documentation.

> **Description**
>
> Opens a specified file and returns a TextStream object that can be
>   used to read from or append to the file.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> object.OpenTextFile(filename[, iomode[, create[, format]]])
> ```
>
> The OpenTextFile method has these parts:

```
Part      Description
----      -----------
object    Required. Always the name of a FileSystemObject.
filename  Required. String expression that identifies the file to open.
iomode    Optional. Indicates input/output mode. Can be one of two constants, either ForReading or ForAppending.
create    Optional. Boolean value that indicates whether a new file can be created if the specified filename doesn't exist. The value is True if a new file is created; False if it isn't created. The default is False.
format    Optional. One of three Tristate values used to indicate the format of the opened file. If omitted, the file is opened as ASCII.
```

Source [OpenTextFile Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: Ok, my error was not specifying what my "ForAppending" was, which should be 8, and didn't need TristateFalse. But after successfully appending to text, The text is in Chinese characters? check edited question.

Comment: Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. If you now have a new or additional question, create a new post and ask it there; you can link back to this one if needed for reference.